# SQL invalid object name

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE Company

SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee
```

Before attempting to select from this table, I already created it. It shows under the tables of the database of the company that I created. But whenever I try to select from it, to insert rows into it, i get this error:

> Invalid object name dbo.Employee

Comment: What do you meant by *select it to add or print it this table*. Are you getting `invalid object name dbo.EMployee` when you do this `SELECT * FROM Company.dbo.Employee`

Comment: yes when i do SELECT * FROM Company.dbo.Employee i got this invalid object name. I meant by select or add : add tuples and select this specific table from others that I created for the Company

Comment: Make sure `Employee` table created in `Company` database. Tell me the result of this below query `Select * from Company.sys.tables where name = 'Employee'`

Comment: It may be different databases or schemes.

Comment: when i ran  your query it showed me a table stating the emplyee's table details(i.e: object_id, principal_id,date created,modified...)
I did create the employee table in Company database

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM Company..Employee` in case the schema is not dbo it should still come up.

Comment: I tried SELECT * FROM Company..Employee but still the same message invalid object name

Comment: How did you create your table? Was it via SQL code (CREATE TABLE) or by using Table designer in SSMS? Can you provide a table create statement or generate one if it was created from SSMS table designer?

Comment: check the default schema for the user

Comment: query that i used to create the employee table:

 USE Company

CREATE TABLE Employee

(Fname Varchar (10) NOT NULL,

Bdate DATE,
Salary DECIMAL (10,2),
Dno INT NOT NULL,
);

Comment: Your table create statement does not specify schema. Please confirm that it was created under dbo schema. You can see schema it in SSMS. Please refresh the SSMS table view (just in case).

Comment: Another simple test. In SSMS Object Explorer can you right click on your table and choose "SELECT TOP 1000". This will open up a new query window and run it. Check the query itself and the connection parameters (e.g. server name)

Comment: it was created under dbo schema

Comment: Check SELECT @@servername in a query where you are trying to select from table. Maybe you are using another instance.

Comment: Run `use Company; select b.*, a.* from sys.tables a inner join sys.schemas b on ( a.schema_id = b.schema_id ) where ( a.object_id = object_id('Employee') );` and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a database name, like "visits.dbo.Employee" .

Just look and see what database the 'Employee' table is being called from.